# XPages associate with SVN

Tags: svn, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

We have an XPages application that we associate with an On-Disk project and the application was originally set up with the On-Disk project linked to SVN and we could perform a Team >> Commit on the On-Disk project.  But now the link from the On-Disk project to SVN appears to have removed itself.  How do I set up the link between the two again?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah!! Found it.  I right clicked on the on-disk project and selected Team >> Share project.

This provided me with SVN repositories already set up and I just opted for the one the on-disk project used to be asscoiated with and after selecting I was then asked what files I wanted to commit.